# How to calculate the stake required to win $\$X$ at $Y$ odds

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, gambling

I want to cover a $\$100$ bet I have on the Hawthorn Hawks winning the [Australian Football League](http://www.afl.com.au) grand final.

If they lose the grand final, I lose my $\$100$.

Another team, Geelong Cats, are at $\$4.25$ to win the grand final.

How do I calculate the stake required at odds of $4.25$ to win a $100$ dollar profit from the bet (which might cover my Hawks bet if Geelong win). i.e. If I put $31$ dollars on at $4.25$, I would receive $131.75$ if I won my bet. Take away my $31$ dollar stake, and I am left with $\$100.75$.

I want to know the equation to calculate what exact stake I need to make a profit of $\$100$.

Note: I'm a hobby gambler.

Comment: For your last question, this is becase $\$$ is used to initialise the $\LaTeX$ environment, I've spruced up your post for you.

Comment: How do I enter the $ you used?

Comment: $ \$\backslash$ \$ $: basically: [dollar sign][backslash][dollar sign][dollar sign]

Comment: @ZainPatel: For a more 'semantically meaningful' way you can also use `&dollar;`

Comment: @user21820 thank you, I should have looked that up in hindsight! :-P

Comment: The dollar sign is used to initiate an expression for a formula, written in the LaTeX math language (or MathJax). For example, if I surround back-slash frac{1}{\pi} with two dollar signs (the back-slash being the one back slash character), it comes out $\frac{1}{\pi}$.  So the dollar sign is treated as a special character; to create something that prints as a dollar sign you need to write the two characters back-slash dollar-sign as in \$4.25.  BTW, at least in America, odds are quoted as 3.25:1 (or 13:4), not \$4.25.

Comment: That got me thinking @MarkFischler. In Australia, we hear bookies on the TV say "Geelong are at $\$$4.25 to win the flag". I googled and found that this is [decimal odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-odds_betting#Decimal_odds). I now see decimal odds are never written with a $\$$ sign, but are spoken (in Australia) with the $\$$ sign).

Comment: I'm having trouble creating links on this SE site. I normally enclose the link text in [ ] and immediately follow it with the link in ( ) but that did not work above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4.25 x = x+100\\
3.25x = 100 \\
x=\frac{100}{3.25} = 30.769
$$
If you bet \$30.77 you come away with  \$130.77; the bookie keeps the odd quarter penny.